# Solving a system of equations in terms of a variable. (Unfortunately, not a high school algebra question)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, optimization

I have the Lagrangian

$
L = \rho(\alpha_1 x_1^\rho + \alpha_2 x_2^\rho) + \lambda(w-(p_1x_1+p_2x_2))
$

I take the first order conditions

$$
p^2 \alpha_1 x_1^{p-1} = \lambda p_1 \\
p^2 \alpha_2 x_2^{p-1} = \lambda p_2 \\
p_1 x_1^\rho + p_2 x_2^\rho = w
$$

From the first two conditions we obtain

$$
\alpha_1 p_2 x_1^{\rho-1} = \alpha_2 p_1 x_2^{\rho-1}
$$

I believe the next step will be to somehow substitute this statement into the 3rd equation to eliminate $x_1$ or $x_2$ but this doesn't seem to work because the powers on the variables are different...

In short, I can't figure out how to get either $x$ in terms that don't include the other $x$. This is homework so I'm not looking for the solution, I'm looking for a useful math-trick that will get me past where I'm stuck.

---

I happen to know what the solution is. I just need help getting there.

$x(p,w) = (w/(p_1^\delta + p_2^\delta))(p_1^{\delta-1}, p_2^{\delta-1})$ where $\delta = \rho/(\rho-1) \in (-\infty, 1)$

---

#### EDIT

I worked the algebra a bit more and I'm stuck again... I have

$$
x_2 = \frac{w}{p_1 \left(\cfrac{\alpha_2 p_1}{\alpha_1 p_2}\right)^{1/(\rho-1)}+p_2}
$$

And likewise I also have

$$
x_1 = \frac{w}{p_2 \left(\cfrac{\alpha_1 p_2}{\alpha_2 p_1}\right)^{1/(\rho-1)}+p_1}
$$

How can I make this look more like the desired equation:

$x(p,w) = (w/(p_1^\delta + p_2^\delta))(p_1^{\delta-1}, p_2^{\delta-1})$ where $\delta = \rho/(\rho-1) \in (-\infty, 1)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually when you want to elliminate a certain variable, you solve two different equations for said variable and equte the results.

Your condition, $\alpha_1 p_2 x_1^{\rho-1} = \alpha_2 p_1 x_2^{\rho-1}$ can be solved to obtain $x_{1}=x_{2}\left(\frac{\alpha_{2}p_{1}}{\alpha_{1}p_{2}}\right)^{\frac{1}{\rho-1}}$.

On the other hand, $p_1 x_1^\rho + p_2 x_2^\rho = w$ can be rearranged to yield $x_{1}=\left(\frac{w-p_{2}x_{2}^{\rho}}{p_{1}}\right)^{1/\rho}$

The variable $x_{1}$ can then be elliminated by equating these two expressions. Can you take things from here?

Comment: Yeah, feeling confident enough now to do it on my own. Thank you! The answer is always obvious after a nudge in the right direction haha

Comment: Good to hear, and good luck! I know exactly what you mean.

Comment: I got around to working the problem a bit more today and I've got myself stuck again... I'm going to edit the question right now but it'd be nice if you could help me

Comment: I can take another look but I will need some more detail. Are you trying to apply and solve the Euler-Lagrange equation associated with your lagrangian? What is $x$? Is it the vector $(x_{1},x_{2})$? What is $p$ in your equation for $x$? Is it $p_{1}$, $p_{2}$ or $\rho$? Which quantities are parameters and which are variables?

Comment: $p$ is $(p_1,p_2)$, likewise for $x$. $\rho$ is a distinct variable

Comment: Thanks. In that case, do you have a typo in your first two first order conditions? $p^2$ does'ny make sense their.